# Using Supernatural Stamina on a Zombie Creature with Diregraf Colossus on the board

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So let's say for instance I am attacking with a [Festering Mummy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFestering%20Mummy%5d) and it's blocked so I use [Supernatural Stamina](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSupernatural%20Stamina%5d) on it because I know it will be destroyed. If I have [Diregraf Colossus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiregraf%20Colossus%5d) in play does the Zombie Card returned act as a spell cast? I was looking at rulings on Supernatural Stamina [here](http://www.mtgassist.com/cards/Amonkhet/Supernatural-Stamina/rulings/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supernatural Stamina adds a *Triggered Ability* to the (in this case) mummy that has an *Effect* of returning the mummy to the battlefield when it dies. This is **not** the same as casting a spell so it does **not** Trigger the Ability of the Diregraf Colossus.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will
>   eventually resolve and have its effect. ...